# Is it possible to make a NOT LIKE filter on the ExecSQL subject of a MAPITable? Outlook Redemption

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Is it possible to make a NOT LIKE filter on the ExecSQL subject of a MAPITable?

I'm doing this filter:

```
MAPITable mt = session.Stores.MAPITable;
mt.Item = inbox.Items;
var records = mt.ExecSQL($"select Subject, EntryID from Inbox Where Subject not like '%[DocSite %'");
```

But I'm having this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   ConsoleApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Assertion failed: Number of fields == 1

If I remove the NOT constrain, the like filter it is apply and works. The problem is the NOT constrain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put parenthesis around like the following and move the `not` operator out?
 $"select Subject, EntryID from Inbox Where not (Subject like '%[DocSite %') "

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thank you for your answer!
I did that change in my code but the same error message is shown.

Comment: Oh, wait, "not" needs to be around (subject like 'blah') - I updated the statement above